# Alternatives to AsyncTask for extensive sending of data to PC/Server

Tags: android, multithreading

I write android app that extensively sends small chunks of data to PC/Server using AsyncTask. It works. But if I rotate my device I end up with dangling async task and for some reason new async task is not even started (I'm new to Java/android development).

I execute my async task during onCreate.
**Question 1**: Why the async task is not starting second time after device rotation?

I already learned that AsyncTask is not good for my background task, it's mostly for short term tasks. **Question 2**: But what should I use instead if I want the background task to: 1. setup connection (open Socket!) 2. wait for data from user (data is generated by the user via interaction with UI) and send the data immediately (and the data chunks are very small). I need to avoid input lags, so the solution must be lightweight and efficient.

Also as I'm new to this, I don't want to use any external libraries...

Answer (score 1):

Use IntentService as alternative or create a subclass of a Service for long operations.
It has many benefits over AsyncTasks and can be called many times. 
Although it doesn't interact with UI directly but with the help of BroadcastReceiver you are covered.

Read more here;

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: I've seen it and trying to reimplement my code with it. However, I worry that performance will be too bad. Let's see. Thanks!

Comment: IntentService does not help, because it's destroyed each time intent is served. But I need to create socket and keep it alive, while sending data from UI. Tried Service, but it's called on main UI thread...

Comment: Asking a right question helps getting correct answer. You didn't not include having socket in.your question, therefore I will advise you to update your question.

Comment: Did you declare your serivc in the Manifest? If yea then what error are you getting?

Comment: I mentioned in my original question that I want this background task/thread/service/whatever to setup connection (via socket) and send data generated in UI (if no data available the thread should wait).

Comment: Service was declared in Manifest. I started first intent on the service to open socket (socket is the member of Service), then started other intent on the "same" service, but it did not keep my socket, because after first intent the Service was destroyed with my socket.

Comment: Create a new class and extend Service and bind you Activity class with that service subclass. Try and have quick scan at the link I sent you before implementing this solution.

Comment: If I open socket in Service I get the following exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException